# GridView2_RowDataBound fires twice after button click

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview

> GridView2_RowDataBound fires twice after button click...strange behavior of gridview...
>
> What i am trying to do is to sum up column values and show it in footer...but instead of adding it for once ...RowDataBound is adding the values two times...showing double the expected result.
>
> Here is my HTML code of GRIDVIEW:::

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" Width="100%" GridLines="None" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
   CssClass="table"  HeaderStyle-CssClass="th" RowStyle-CssClass="td" runat="server"CellPadding="4"    
        OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound" ShowFooter="true" AllowPaging="False"  >
                            <AlternatingRowStyle />
                            <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Count" >
                            <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Labelcalls" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("calls") %>'></asp:Label>
                           </ItemTemplate>
                           <HeaderStyle ></HeaderStyle>
                           <ItemStyle ></ItemStyle>
                           <FooterTemplate>
                           <asp:Label ID="calls" runat="server" />
                           </FooterTemplate>
                           </asp:TemplateField>
                           <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Minutes" >
                           <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:Label ID="Labelmins" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("minutes") %>'></asp:Label>
                           </ItemTemplate>
                           <HeaderStyle ></HeaderStyle>
                           <ItemStyle ></ItemStyle>
                           <FooterTemplate>
                           <asp:Label ID="min" runat="server" />
                          </FooterTemplate>
                           </asp:TemplateField>
                           </Columns>
                           </asp:GridView>
```

> Here is my codebehind for RowDataBound:::

```
protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        total += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "calls"));

    }
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        Label lblTotalPrice = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("calls");
        lblTotalPrice.Text = total.ToString();

    }
}
```

Comment: where is you button which got clicked? have you bind this grid on `Page_Load` also? is your `total` variable define `public static`?

Comment: `RowDataBound` fires not only twice but for every row in the `GridView` including header and footer rows. That's by design. Do you have `DataBind` in `Page_Load` without `!Page.IsPostBack`.-check?

Comment: @ Jitendra Tiwari ...here is my button code:::<asp:Button ID="ImageButton3" runat="server"  OnClick="ImgBtn3_search_Click"  ValidationGroup="cdr" Width="205px" Text="CLIENT" CssClass="styled-select2" Height="35px" Visible="False" />     and nothing is bind on my page load...

Comment: @Tim Schmelter ....no tim i dont have anything on my pageload

Comment: You can look for two things: (1) The event handler being attached in code-behind (`GridView2.RowDataBound += ...`) in addition to being attached in markup; (2) `GridView2.DataBind()` being called twice.